# Difference between Dynamic Factor Model (DFM) and Dynamic Linear Model (DLM)

Tags: dlm

one simple question: what is the difference between a Dynamic Factor Model (DFM) and a Dynamic Linear Model (DLM) ?

Comment: You might get better answers if you tell us what you think the answer is, where you are stuck, and what other steps you have taken to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not the same. Usually, DFM refers to a particular DLM where you assume the observables are dependent on an state vector of reduced dimension with no other structure: think of a PCA in which the principal components are allowed to evolve over time. DLM on the other hand refers to the situation in which the state elements may be related, have tendencies, seasonal effects, etc.